# Bloquear e desbloquear edição de um EditText

Tags: android, edittext

No trecho de código a baixo eu desabilito a edição do valor do frete quando o tipo do frete for SIF porem o trecho de código `Library.editTexPermission(edtFrete, true);` que deveria liberar a edição do editText não funciona na seguinte situação: Selecioar SIF e depois selecionar FOB. Pergunta como posso liberar a edição do `edtFrete` após bloqueá-la?

```
        spFrete.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            switch (spFrete.getSelectedItemPosition()) {
                case 0: {  //FOB
                    Library.editTexPermission(edtFrete, true);

                    break;
                }

                case 1: {  //SIF
                    Library.editTexPermission(edtFrete, false);
                    edtFrete.setText("0.0");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
```

Segue a baixo o trecho de código do `editTexPermission` com ele fica evidente como a edição é bloqueada agora a pergunta é: como setar o KeyListener novamente?

```
public static void editTexPermission(EditText editText, Boolean enabled) {
    editText.setFocusable(enabled);
    if (!enabled)
        editText.setKeyListener(null);
}
```

Comment: Tem como postar o código do `editTexPermission` ?

Comment: Pronto Marco, código postado na pergunta

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o contexto da situação, mas para habilitar e desabilitar o campo você não deveria usar o `editText.setEnabled(true/false)` ?

Comment: Pois é, como disse esse trecho não era meu, eu até achei que a Library era algo do próprio Android! Com simples busca na net descobri que o `setKeyListener` impede qualquer tipo de ação sobre o `EditText`, até mesmo a seleção e cópia de seu conteúdo porem é complicado torna-lo editável novamente sem ter recarregar o fragment. Vou alterar o texto para o que você sugeriu. Por favor poste como respostar para que possa positiva-lo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para bloquear e desbloquear a edição do edittext use a propriedade `setEnabled`do componente, por exemplo :

```
editText.setEnabled(true);
editText.setEnabled(false);
```